# Sitecore SXA Social Share

Tags: sxa

We are working on SXA 1.7.1 & Sitecore 9.0.2 and need to have social share feature for 5 networking sites like FB,Twitter,G+,linkedIn &  Pintreset and looking for kind of interface shown below. Is it possible to have this kind of feature using SXA 1.7.1 OOB?

[image]

Comment: in the earlier release I guess SXA 1.3, it had the AddThis available but there were issues, so It is now not available.

Comment: For www.concentra.com I created a custom Social Share component that generates links that you style. Might be able to achieve this with page list or linked list.

Comment: From Sitecore documentation it seems that AddThis is still there is not taken  Off do we have issues with this component . See this link https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants#_Social

Comment: I guess that's for you to discover. In our case he also needed the component to render a links that are unique to each article.

Comment: Welcome @AlivorTikos in great Sitecore Community first of all. Hopefully my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

We have used SXA 1.7.1 and its AddThis component together with our AddThis account. No need to implement this if you are using SXA and you need to have similar widget as you have in your question.

In AddThis website Tools, we have configured two website tools:

- Follow Button Inline
- Share Button Floating

[image]

But you can select only one based on your requirements. Whether to have it inline or floating.

We have placed pubid identification number generated in AddThis to styling options of SXA Addthis component in the footer Partial design therefore we gave visitors possibility to follow our company accounts:

[image]

We have also added HTML code component from “Follow Button Inline” tool to enable showing this component on page / footer:

[image]

This is how it looks like in Experience Editor in Edit mode:

[image]

We have placed “Share Button Floating” widget on the side to gave visitors possibility to share currently visited page on various social media:

[image]

For this widget, we didn’t have to do any special settings in SXA as we had AddThis code in footer already so AddThis is placing this widget automatically which was great for our purposes.

In AddThis website dashboard, you can see really nice representation of data:

[image]

You can also check my blog for implementing more social features for Sitecore:
https://tothecore.sk/2018/03/29/social-sharing-in-sitecore-9/

Answer (score 0):

Posting an update today (May 3rd, 2023) because Oracle has announced that AddThis will be turned off on **May 31, 2023**. Because of this, Sitecore has deprecated the SXA AddThis component starting on that date and there will no longer be a solution out-of-the-box with SXA.

I put some details here: https://jasonstcyr.com/2023/05/03/remove-your-addthis-component-by-may-31-2023/

**Relevant links:**

- [Sitecore KB article](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002996)
- [Oracle announcement on AddThis.com](https://www.addthis.com/)
- [Related blog by David San Filippo](https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/04/19/sitecore-sxas-social-share-component-will-no-longer-work-after-may-2023/) (Perficient)